# Critical point in function of several real variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I got problem proving this statement:

> Let $f:U\to R$, $U\subseteq R^n $ is open. if  $\vec{a}\in U$ is local Maxima or local minima, then $\vec{a} $ is a critical point.

The definition I got for critical point is:

> Let $f:U\to R $, $U\subseteq R^n $ is open. $\vec{a}\in U$ is called critical point if:
>
> (1) $f$ doesn't differentiable at the point $\vec{a}$
>
> (2)$f$ differentiable at the point $\vec{a}$ and $(\nabla f)(\vec{a})=\vec{0}^{\ t}$

I saw a proof which assumes $(\nabla f)(\vec{a})\ne\vec{0}^{\ t}$, and therefore for small enough $h\in R$, $h>0$ we get:
$$f(\vec{a}+h((\nabla f)(\vec{a}))^{t})>f(\vec{a})$$ which is in contradiction to maxima.

But I don't understand why is have to be larger the $f(\vec{a})$.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, this is true because the gradient of $f$ points in the direction that *increases* $f$ the fastest.  Formally, using Taylor's theorem:
$$
    f(\vec a + h ((\nabla f)(\vec a))^t)
    = f(\vec a)
      + h \Vert (\nabla f)(\vec a) \Vert^2
      + R_2(\vec a,h ((\nabla f)(\vec a))^t)
$$
where $\frac{R_2(\vec a,\vec x)}{\Vert \vec x\Vert^2} \to 0$ as $\vec x\to 0$.  Because of the vanishing remainder,  you can choose $h$ small enough so that the right-hand side is larger than $f(\vec a)$.